# QGIS printing shift on WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator base?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis-2.8

I've had this problem before but I'm not succeeding in fixing it using what I thought worked before.  This has been brought up as an issue previously, but I'm stuck when I apply the previous answers.  There must be numerous people doing the same thing.

I am running QGIS 2.8.2 on Mac OS X (10.10 Yosemite) with OpenLayers 1.3.6

- I start off a new project by using the OpenLayers plugin to connect to Google or Bing Maps.
- I confirm or set the project projection to EPSG3857 for WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator.
- Then I add a layer in a different project (happens to be IRENET95).
- Zoom to the new layer and everything fits very nicely on the screen.
- Open a new Print Composer and add a map.  Things look good on the screen still.
- Export as a pdf or image and the image base seems to have shifted.

Am I missing something simple or obvious here? In case this is not all clear I've attached two images below.  The first is the screen (of Print Composer) and the second is the exported file.

[image: Part of the QGIS map window with everything fitting]

[image: Part of an image exported from Print Composer]

Comment: this is a long-standing issue...

Comment: BTW if this is still an ongoing issue i would be interested in finding out more about it and even taking a look through the code.  Preferably if there are some clues about where to start ;-)

Comment: Well I see that this was a bug that has been fixed/closed http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4223 but I see it a few places mentioned after that http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=openlayers+print+shift

Comment: Yes I found that too.  It was classified as fixed and closed a while ago (couple or so QGIS versions ago), but although it was closed I'm not clear about the fixed part.  Perhaps a sidebar in the documentation would be worth setting up if there is a standard workaround.